# Mapper not executing on the hostname returned from getLocations() of InputSplit in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, input-split

I have extended the `InputSplit` class of Hadoop to calculate my custom input split, however while am returning a particular HostIP(i.e datanode IP) as string for the overridden **getLocations()**, the Map Task for it is not being executed on that HostIP instead its executing on some other.What would be the issue for not executing on that particular HostIP?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try returning the fully qualified name from getLocations. I was facing a similar issue, but returning qualified name looked to have worked for me.

Thanks,
Srivatsan